# Sails js Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

My code has been working, but when I updated to sails 0.12.1, from 0.11 this issue started happening. 
I have been through other similar posts, but to my understanding none fits into my issue and all suggested solutions are not an issue in my case. Especially since this worked before updated.

AngularController call:

```
$http.get('/getS',{ 
     p_id: p.id,
     limit: 5
})
...
```

And yes I have console.log() both the id and limit value, they are not NaN.

Routes (have tried both):

```
'GET /getS'                  : {controller: 'SController', action: 'getS', skipAssets:true},
'GET /getS'                  : 'SController.getS',
```

Controller: if I log the id and limit values they are NaN for some unknown reason. Also, req.allParams() shows empty.

```
getS: function(req, res){
    var id = req.param('p_id');
    var max = req.param('limit');
    P_s.find()
        .where({p_id:id})
        .limit(max)
        .sort('createdAt desc')
    ...
```

This is clearly not something I have done wrong, how can this be fixed?

I do multiple other http.gets, they all work. A potential difference though is that this http.get is done inside another http.gets response(.then{}).

Comment: have you tried to sails.log(req) ?

Comment: yip, tried it. But it logs out to much data for the cmd line, cuts off the relevant info at the top @Bonanza

Comment: try sails.log(req.route); sails.log(req.params);

Comment: Awesome, helped. But shows empty params[] in both. The only time I can see the two values is in the error response, it shows the values there somehow.. this must be a issue with sails itself?

Comment: Now i see. [Sails params](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-param) when you pass them after question mark they are visible as req.query object .

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like that is also empty. Tried to print out sails.log(req.query) but its empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107862/discussion-between-bonanza-and-cfl).

Comment: As a temporary solution changed http.get to http.post, it is now working. This should not be the answer though, 'incorrect' to use post here. Thanks to @Bonanza for the idea

Comment: there is req.param('pid'); not 'p_id'

Comment: @waza007 Thanks, true. I edited the code before posting it here though, was just a edit mistake. My code is correct. I edited the post